# How to make it an integer?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

in view.py:

```
return redirect('/website/detail/{0}/'.format(pk))
```

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.productDetailView,name='productDetailView'),
```

pk is integer type but when I am passing it through **'/website/detail/{0}/'.format(pk)** this is becoming string. So I am getting this error:

```
TypeError at /website/detail/1/
must be real number, not str
```

I can solve it changing the url pattern. But I don't want that.

So how can I pass **pk** as **integer**?

Comment: must be real number, not str

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not use simple representation

```
return redirect('productDetailView',pk=pk)
```